# Crash Log for Iphone on taping the icon in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I got a crash in some of the device iphone 4 and iphone 4S on taping the application icon on the phone.Where as in some phone the same ipa files works fine.

iPhone 4 :- ios 0.6.1
iphone 4S :- ios 0.6.1

The crash log for iphone 4s  is:-

```
Incident Identifier: 51DF8CE5-B5AE-4EE3-912E-E6943C29DAA9
CrashReporter Key:   c7b543a8de5c8cb54f577694dd9badeabba8d4a1
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         CallEmergency [23705]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/153DBCAD-1500-46F8-901D-4690E47106AA/CallEmergency.app/CallEmergency
Identifier:      CallEmergency
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-01-18 15:51:54.212 +1100
OS Version:      iOS 6.0.1 (10A523)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x3937129e 0x3326097a 0x392bcb70 0xe68d6 0x3416ca6a 0x393465da 0x3934628c 0x39344efc 0x392b7eb8 0x392b7d44 0x376852e6 0x324f72f4 0xe0486 0xe0414)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31067350 0x31056000 + 70480
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x343f611e 0x343c7000 + 192798
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3443296e 0x343c7000 + 440686
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37552d4a 0x3754f000 + 15690
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3754fff4 0x3754f000 + 4084
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33260a74 0x33258000 + 35444
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37550078 0x3754f000 + 4216
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37550110 0x3754f000 + 4368
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37551594 0x3754f000 + 9620
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x332609cc 0x33258000 + 35276
10  CoreFoundation                  0x392b7f1c 0x392af000 + 36636
11  CoreFoundation                  0x392b7d44 0x392af000 + 36164
12  GraphicsServices                0x376852e6 0x37680000 + 21222
13  UIKit                           0x324f72f4 0x324a0000 + 357108
14  CallEmergency                   0x000e0486 0xdf000 + 5254
15  CallEmergency                   0x000e0414 0xdf000 + 5140

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31067d98 0x31056000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x343cdcf6 0x343c7000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x343cda12 0x343c7000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x343cd8a0 0x343c7000 + 26784

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31057648 0x31056000 + 5704
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3766a974 0x37662000 + 35188
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3766a654 0x37662000 + 34388

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31067d98 0x31056000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x343cdcf6 0x343c7000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x343cda12 0x343c7000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x343cd8a0 0x343c7000 + 26784

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31056eb4 0x31056000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31057048 0x31056000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                  0x39346040 0x392af000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                  0x39344d9e 0x392af000 + 613790
4   CoreFoundation                  0x392b7eb8 0x392af000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                  0x392b7d44 0x392af000 + 36164
6   WebCore                         0x34f96a40 0x34f8c000 + 43584
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x343d830e 0x343c7000 + 70414
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x343d81d4 0x343c7000 + 70100

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3a349534
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3a349b88      r6: 0x1ed9e274      r7: 0x2fd21a24
    r8: 0x1ed9e250    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x00120364     r11: 0x0012035c
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fd21a18      lr: 0x343f6123      pc: 0x31067350
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
   0xdf000 -   0x112fff +CallEmergency armv7  <cb030730c7893c0abd86c3050d2431b6> /var/mobile/Applications/153DBCAD-1500-46F8-901D-4690E47106AA/CallEmergency.app/CallEmergency
0x2feee000 - 0x2ff0efff  dyld armv7  <75594988728831d98e1f7c4c7b7ca29d> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30988000 - 0x3098dfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <3a351ca1d4ae3146a787f3e13564294b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x30a65000 - 0x30a6afff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <021ff140d6003f3281dfa29b79fa9e6e> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x30a6b000 - 0x30bbbfff  MusicLibrary armv7  <2010302aff03397d97f7f91b446ec661> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x30bef000 - 0x30bfbfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <a3bba3842596315a81aa171a8bbda7b5> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x30ce6000 - 0x30d21fff  AppSupport armv7  <74ed50d2f7d23ce696b029dd817749c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x30d22000 - 0x30d87fff  CoreMedia armv7  <28a1fe1e729d37e0bb623201b2652a45> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x30dd0000 - 0x30ddafff  MailServices armv7  <f31a7844317a3f2484cffe092e9fd7c2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x31056000 - 0x3106cfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <4c2862d2e8f23119bfe114b0662c6241> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x312df000 - 0x312dffff  vecLib armv7  <66204595f7653ef29e5e26cb8629177a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31369000 - 0x3137afff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <a3d025234d1a3880a0e5f87879633ee0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x3137c000 - 0x3139ffff  MobileSync armv7  <986186369add34f1be231f5a47d2fd2c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x313c6000 - 0x3159efff  ImageIO armv7  <fdfa8aa6307235b29435e5c8f6bc9819> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x316d2000 - 0x3171efff  QuickLook armv7  <9f69026f4b7837429b824a115eeef615> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x3171f000 - 0x31857fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903960bfcfe93adb943752851f88491e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31869000 - 0x31a02fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <b283f42b49793e61b25341fea2830ff5> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x31a2d000 - 0x31a34fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <257ecb171a363e4298a63f72d7fffea2> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x31a53000 - 0x31a5afff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7  <6e39f8511ecc3c3489829714eb6fde12> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x31a5d000 - 0x31afdfff  UIFoundation armv7  <795a2f216cc3379c95eb645c633cc527> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x31afe000 - 0x31b01fff  ActorKit armv7  <64235ea1a8b73d23a4a9836410424b6b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x31b18000 - 0x31b57fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <44d84d23d10f344c90b4d9e9611ec976> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x31b58000 - 0x31b7cfff  Bom armv7  <c76b4156e0463ecb922608d44c126d86> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x31b7f000 - 0x31b7ffff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <f2cad3bd15f63f448a9c5be732c65819> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x31bbd000 - 0x31bc1fff  FTClientServices armv7  <2cf901e7aedb3f3b9ea08b465f0e5d14> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x31c52000 - 0x31c8ffff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <7db25f3d55b93f31868e37326fba1e57> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x323ba000 - 0x3243ffff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <759ca29f533a33e88a81fddc3364bf19> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x324a0000 - 0x329f3fff  UIKit armv7  <4f85b22a1eb73af08641066b29c4edb2> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x329f4000 - 0x32a68fff  ProofReader armv7  <cc89a352199a393ba0e46af69e670ef9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x32a93000 - 0x32acdfff  iTunesStore armv7  <90c74a32628d3905aa224948b4d52bcf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x32ace000 - 0x32bbbfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <faa5abb937e3306ab87c7f7c38315839> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x32d56000 - 0x32d6bfff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <9fbb123276823c2383fc34b7a55404d7> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x32d6c000 - 0x32daafff  VideoToolbox armv7  <250b8df69b3c3f929f30463d218b7462> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x32dab000 - 0x32dadfff  OAuth armv7  <d3e2bc9ae64b31f0a89c52dc1c2797fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x32dfc000 - 0x32ea7fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <fba51e235adc368b8132db578723a8fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x32ed9000 - 0x32fb1fff  StoreServices armv7  <49ff779e3e783e7ca6b56b5788c2c119> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x32fd7000 - 0x32fdafff  MobileSystemServices armv7  <6edd9c74c5a73c33809152446abe1538> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x32fdb000 - 0x330c1fff  AVFoundation armv7  <d3f2b9d750c83e818c39cbb5ed609244> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x331e8000 - 0x331e9fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <46cd200d99323aebbf6d81e5fb16424f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x331fb000 - 0x33208fff  ApplePushService armv7  <420684556cd430b09a6d9ec6d328d53d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x33209000 - 0x33246fff  FTServices armv7  <754c08bad5333c0a9cd49db9bfa2e75f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x33258000 - 0x33356fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <5224e803eca737a4b2c6451d136b3d28> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x33367000 - 0x33380fff  Notes armv7  <b8fb864f5973319083f926d9a570734e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x333d7000 - 0x333e3fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <e98708fbfa683df2a91d45dc765071a7> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x333e4000 - 0x33669fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <e8b0007c7e3c3275a5c1fe8ce98839d1> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x3366a000 - 0x336ccfff  CoreText armv7  <4a0bece315e9316fa1aa1b5923740f55> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x336d3000 - 0x336eafff  BackBoardServices armv7  <a5570d37cd3f30cbb9572a9cdb824126> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x33722000 - 0x337d7fff  CoreImage armv7  <ad658acd554a386fb81bb137a237b5f4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x337ee000 - 0x338a7fff  Message armv7  <2979dbe859f6313f983b1737bff8214c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x338ae000 - 0x3399dfff  GeoServices armv7  <60e2738ccb9635e9874907d54ea27b68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x339c6000 - 0x339f4fff  Security armv7  <fb75984442a435cd84aac722142d5a44> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x339f5000 - 0x339f5fff  Accelerate armv7  <22bee3e96cbc3538bfc50ca5be618cc0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x339fa000 - 0x339fafff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <b25697291f6237feb3458df23485a759> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x33a68000 - 0x33aa4fff  DataAccess armv7  <0bf16fd4f4bd37efbb1a3617750a0dbb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x33aaa000 - 0x33ad0fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <134c41c587fb33dca014bd525f68a0c7> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x33b80000 - 0x33b9ffff  WebBookmarks armv7  <ed705f425035329d96ede473f023ed84> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x33ba0000 - 0x33bf5fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <e5b7289acd1231acb950569a81c10ac1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33c6c000 - 0x33c6ffff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <2a9fe0b48f473d0f8fe2bf076cd12753> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x33fb8000 - 0x34011fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <ad4c53081a263f0d96f63b9a80f2ae91> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x34012000 - 0x34023fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <8b9821bc87ba354297392cb50da7be58> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x340c4000 - 0x34287fff  Foundation armv7  <2e1ac190c4f837e2a1059043dd7b1c63> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x34295000 - 0x342e1fff  IMFoundation armv7  <fd1c50ba98f9307f8b06d074aed412b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x342fc000 - 0x343c6fff  Celestial armv7  <bf58f2db2e333ea18da2f7abd0d89ae6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x343c7000 - 0x3444dfff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <d45dc8901531343caf9b7e703d3eba50> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x344f0000 - 0x345a3fff  EventKit armv7  <b5a1d18f2ced31bfb385952f4c390ea4> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x34904000 - 0x34ab9fff  CoreData armv7  <a42aa4f0f01833c390bc8c6c394dda1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x34bff000 - 0x34e85fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6a4804d0e35e362dbad6f047c25227ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x34e86000 - 0x34eabfff  OpenCL armv7  <f7e2cb8404653022bf5cdea17bc5d06f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x34ee3000 - 0x34f1efff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <bc5b8d4a10863ce192acf26428e68da7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x34f76000 - 0x34f8bfff  libmis.dylib armv7  <3afeeea531013420af75315d8d6dd332> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x34f8c000 - 0x358bbfff  WebCore armv7  <29cc251f63fe3a9eb16e96742b88ac4f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x358c4000 - 0x358c6fff  MessageSupport armv7  <44d449b4959a33b99d4ab4a9cd161ee6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
0x358f2000 - 0x3594bfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <d831f1f9285535acac5035a29d84aaaf> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x35a44000 - 0x35acbfff  CoreMotion armv7  <a3df71772fe1315aa6d176cac1ac48e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x35acc000 - 0x35ad0fff  IOSurface armv7  <959e67366a553eca85e6ccfa2d668366> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x35b25000 - 0x35b28fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <df4096b1cdc5335790db9a2a51e6b029> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x35b29000 - 0x35b2cfff  libcache.dylib armv7  <e08b913e17753180b91728a8bd5dda7b> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x35b41000 - 0x35b50fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <5c91ef875c5931a1a26e227ddfd7262d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x35d77000 - 0x35e8cfff  QuartzCore armv7  <d96571a6986c3012b315cb860f4d65ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x35e8d000 - 0x35e9bfff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <d0fb0eda6cb53a4da859d598c59e7522> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x35edd000 - 0x35ef5fff  EAP8021X armv7  <c3678853424030f9a2e410c5488aea5f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x35f29000 - 0x35f44fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <51845c89677f3e77aeb221c44bda48f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x35f6d000 - 0x35f72fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <7bde3532f2953f3894eb725379575926> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x360f7000 - 0x36100fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <5258dce78afc3fd7934a5674b92ad785> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3610d000 - 0x36119fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <0338ce49444332ec88cfc45c624bb39b> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3611c000 - 0x36122fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9e8bfe02e370375ea8439ab895528982> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x3613a000 - 0x36143fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <43de6d03af0838f2a1eeec10d4149e9d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x3614a000 - 0x3622dfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <56d8e00447133cd89457deec007327cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x3622e000 - 0x36241fff  AirTraffic armv7  <050ad0f6ad67391d9ff4ac52b3989981> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x36363000 - 0x36369fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <690aaa493b5c3f9582499f174adf4964> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3636a000 - 0x363c2fff  CoreLocation armv7  <7bca9c29b3d23f61ba0e28af9e8ee357> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x363c3000 - 0x363cafff  OpenGLES armv7  <e035b741746c316dba8f1e59a568bf17> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x363f8000 - 0x363fafff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <7add7c91a2673641b0c5f0433a203da6> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x364cf000 - 0x36505fff  MIME armv7  <32427c81a9933c4796d1a37a88a3ac44> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x36506000 - 0x36523fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <cd76b3fcb0db3922ad62f547ab2e55fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x36539000 - 0x36559fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <7f6f63b31f333c41952f685fdd54a6cb> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x3655e000 - 0x365c2fff  AddressBook armv7  <bdf14ca2b4fb32e5bdb2a9fafb460f09> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x365c3000 - 0x365c4fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <6a0dd04f0710329b9c1722db2235f5c3> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x365c5000 - 0x3660efff  IOKit armv7  <635953fdb81237e991ab57ccff92e97d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3663a000 - 0x3663bfff  DataMigration armv7  <25f8874067393208acc083124bc3eb86> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x36655000 - 0x36685fff  ContentIndex armv7  <25cc27c7fdac34e6ae5e057c048a3e21> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x36686000 - 0x36686fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <1fd63e8305ab3ca190b1ef6ab2555f9d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x36687000 - 0x36688fff  CoreSurface armv7  <aa216ca3e2e0381ea8cf9abbd6f430f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3688b000 - 0x36890fff  CommonUtilities armv7  <cb484bdaf5003e4baa13f83bafff62a9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x368d9000 - 0x36a7ffff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <8171afa18a08371c89cab6c9d823d1c5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x36a80000 - 0x36a89fff  MediaRemote armv7  <dbc251adcad43e72a31427f836a060cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x36a97000 - 0x36ae2fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <55a7612b28c43cfcad7089b688591b80> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x36ae9000 - 0x36aeefff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <15aa2c3c8d523273913d4fc6717d3b7c> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x36b22000 - 0x36b23fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <3a149b4730663b1ea84e4a0a68ccc689> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x36b24000 - 0x36b5ffff  iCalendar armv7  <d5f593ead35b38a98d6cfd4a243e0172> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x36b63000 - 0x36b6dfff  IAP armv7  <6703a23c7d263f33992f15c7f407b50a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x36bac000 - 0x36bb3fff  XPCObjects armv7  <5bc4f7282e9d3945a6c1885217670667> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x36dde000 - 0x36e11fff  AppleAccount armv7  <2af09d814a5a382192613b68b9327d49> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x36e38000 - 0x36efdfff  CFNetwork armv7  <3e973794a4d13428bb974edcb2027139> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x36f34000 - 0x36fb9fff  MessageUI armv7  <8a69ee961ad135b78152a45d31a2fc8e> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x36fba000 - 0x36fd0fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <9b3fd56781103f209be2c43e48c1efc9> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x36fd1000 - 0x36fd8fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <c1a469c6ca4a3718bef325ec0f4e1885> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x3702d000 - 0x370e7fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <3da0ecfaea4937148cd365af1d7515c2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x37177000 - 0x37177fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <8a2e3a8fdf9335e2867a33e2d1a9baf8> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x371b2000 - 0x371cafff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <be3d5625aed733ffb2d53400655fe110> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x371cb000 - 0x371ccfff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <6c912cedc1e938ad914dfce91a529b68> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x371cd000 - 0x371d1fff  CertUI armv7  <7e4aee03dc3735559f1270e504d94f02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x371d2000 - 0x371d5fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <e6b6ae9d4f5f3831a40fcc370afc1429> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x37204000 - 0x37211fff  TelephonyUtilities armv7  <19dbc34167323bca9510012b926d8cf7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x37277000 - 0x372cdfff  CoreAudio armv7  <a3a2eb3a29443b42a23aa8ecb1232846> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x372e0000 - 0x37308fff  PrintKit armv7  <a8ef6136b9773d42ac20f7eb54279039> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x373c2000 - 0x373cefff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <74d50f4c8d243a35ad3ae89d85f2793a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x373cf000 - 0x373e8fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <e1f8d258d02c344cb0d17cec31818d3f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x37424000 - 0x37430fff  AccountSettings armv7  <0b7524e9a8ef36bf9e9f6a5c445478af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x37502000 - 0x37513fff  Accounts armv7  <07b95faa96e73ffeb52694cbad7f3528> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x37519000 - 0x3754efff  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7  <ebd023957d853fa8bd35309592e92dac> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x3754f000 - 0x37562fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <c5a5f03138353747b539e620ef2bb5c0> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x375c0000 - 0x375c2fff  TCC armv7  <f641dd0500fa3f0087d93da665ea84b8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x375c6000 - 0x375dbfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e79b59a3406f34d9b37f8085955115ce> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x37662000 - 0x3767ffff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <4abccf75caf33fa5a0c6037b2e1c5f41> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x37680000 - 0x3768bfff  GraphicsServices armv7  <c5879083e8693aba827c78a32abe2391> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x376eb000 - 0x376f3fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <359ccc7700c93d58adbbd74ecfda80d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x37700000 - 0x3771cfff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7  <7b2a25c750063de480f6a691f716b9d7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x3771d000 - 0x3772ffff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <000fb77814ee3ca0841e14bbba48867d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x37997000 - 0x37997fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <a04b639c18593885bd81bfa623a6f07c> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x379ca000 - 0x379d3fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e51cbfefefbc30b6b47d99739123033e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x379d4000 - 0x379d4fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <993c9bfe8bf031548b9ddba63cc17015> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x37de3000 - 0x37de9fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <a81d768a49cf37a1a111594d39cea3fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x37dfb000 - 0x37e01fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <6c1c1aaf9a3537d7ada4b519d14da7ab> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x38550000 - 0x385a8fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <fa250e174ca43d3c93a61e41f0df9771> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x3860c000 - 0x38610fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <6a8f59f89218372d9f24c4193a179008> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x38639000 - 0x3863afff  IOAccelerator armv7  <de8af6be681832008d180d7424d55f0d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x3864b000 - 0x386f8fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <ef245c0afc113f54b6f30921671edab2> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x38848000 - 0x388c5fff  HomeSharing armv7  <50bd2fe02665322695fbab9f2693bcd7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x38a25000 - 0x38a6ffff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <a361a382693032b9bdfb2860033b3024> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x38e25000 - 0x38f63fff  vImage armv7  <a7fd7fcd7041356db2ca297402ab6e8c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x38f64000 - 0x38f73fff  CoreVideo armv7  <092f3aa965803a1aaea69af2ac5143f5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x38f74000 - 0x38f79fff  Marco armv7  <19d5931d02523a459c75954d3d517e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x390a2000 - 0x391ebfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <0253932c1b9038a0849ef73c38e076ca> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x391ee000 - 0x39266fff  IMCore armv7  <38d8b5270ff636f1b6640fe5adee05a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x39282000 - 0x39284fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <4fd03b13dbfe32628adc789367f48ce1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x392af000 - 0x393e1fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <e30fc309df7b3c9f8ac57f0f6047d65f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x39412000 - 0x39825fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <0cb7a12beb3d32c1abd1834be8328b7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x39840000 - 0x3991cfff  WebKit armv7  <2b33136aa86e383a83d32908bddc9667> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3991d000 - 0x3991dfff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <85e7546accc23ae1a973da4758512b7f> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3991e000 - 0x3994bfff  MobileAsset armv7  <7ef1c10c0c493ad4b0073de317f2448d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x39980000 - 0x39c35fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <dd6f3958c3d536d6be90836682d2ffee> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
```

Comment: Without symbolicating the crash report there is nothing anybody can say. There are plenty of descriptions all over the net on how to do that. One example that also helps understanding these reports: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

Comment: @Kerni I am not getting crash from the xcode..This is the crash log which i got from the device.. while executing the application from the itunes..

Comment: It does not matter from where you get the crash report Drag it into the "Device Logs" section of the Xcode organizer to get it symbolicated. If the symbolication doesn't completely work, search the hundreds of related questions that are already answered multiple times all over the place.